# PHP if/else condition is somehow overriding CSS

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

A login page that recognizes users by session exist, if session exists it will type their name, if not it will produce a 'hello user, please register'.

The if condition works perfect, yet the else condition for the non existent session is not applying my main.css rules, but it does apply the bootstrap.css.
my head loads the Jquery first, then bootstrap and then my main.css.

```
<div id="full-background">
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Hello <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['usr_name'].'</h1><script>$(\'#full-background\').delay(1200).animate({
            \'opacity\': 0
        }, 1900, function () {
            $(this).animate({
                zIndex: -1
            }, 10, function () {
                console.log(\'finished zIndex\');
            });
            }
        );</script>';
            }else{
                echo 'User</h1><button>Click Here to Register</button>';} ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: this is where ur main css shud be applied : "'User</h1><button>Click Here to Register</button>"

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile what do you mean? it's already applied in the head of the page.

Comment: "else condition for the non existent session is not applying my main.css rules" ? I mean you wanna style the text in the else block?

Comment: yes, but I already stated that the head loads the CSS which applies to everything on the page, even the background, the only thing that it's not taking is the `H1` and `button` text, which are wrapped in `text-box` `div`

Comment: the h1 and button are taking the style from the bootstrap css why not give a class to your button and also the h1 and apply a style it should work,